# I can t find my internal HDD drive (part of fusion drive) on iMac 27 late 2012

Tags: macos, imac, fusion-drive

Hello as I wrote on the title I have an issue with my fusion drive .. After entering internet recovery mode I only see the SSD ... Here is the photo also from my diskutil list and diskutil cs list :

[image]

[image]

Before that I took a messages twice that the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer .. This is the reason I entered Internet Recovery mode ..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47720/discussion-on-question-by-basilayr-i-can-t-find-my-internal-hdd-drive-part-of-f).

Answer (score 1):

It could be a hardware failure. You could test that by installing the OS in recovery mode to an external drive (USB/FireWire/Thunderbolt are all supported for booting) and then seeing if you can wipe both the HDD and SSD or set up Fusion Drive again.

This delays spending time and money on a repair tech. Or spending the time to decide if you can attempt a DIY repair or want to get it to a certified / trained tech that has access to Apple repair parts and tools.

Comment: I now install the OS to the SSD part .. is there any way to do something from there ??

Comment: Sure. If you can't erase and repartition the drive from a booted OS then you have a hardware failure. We should probably talk in [chat] -  you have so many discs in the disc you tell that it's hard to know what is connected really. Can you get that cut down to basically one or two drives?

Comment: I installed Sierra OS ..in disk utility again only saws the SSD drive ..I run the etrecheck program and in configuration files it says with red exactly this : /etc/sudoers, File size 1275 but expected 1563 ..

Comment: https://s15.postimg.org/j8pmninij/Screenshot_2016_10_30_21_31_21.png    @bmike did you mean something like this ??